# getting undefined message from useEffect console log reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here is the response data returned from console.log(response.data) in the useEffect.

[image]

[image]

And the code here:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
const [categoryList, SetCategoryList] = useState([])

useEffect(async() => {       
        const response = await Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/users/allusers', {withCredentials:true})
    console.log(response.data) //return data
    console.log(response.data.categoryaccess) //undefined
    SetCategoryList(response.data.categoryaccess)
    setUserData(response.data)     
    }, [])
```

What I am trying to achieve is to join the array as one string. For example, 5feb2122a8632e0550deb43b,5fec781a52b5cf23c0f34333,5fedeec19604432ac034bf89 separated by a comma.

How do I access the categoryaccess array data and join them as a single string? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. thanks

Comment: response.data is an array. `response.data[0].categoryaccess`

Comment: `response.data` is clearly an array (denoted by `[{..}, {..}]`). You might want to use `response.data[0].categoryaccess`, or use all array elements to get to the final result (depending on what you want to do with the other elements).

Comment: hi caramiriel, actually I have 2 arrays. I have update the question with another set of picture. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because I believe you are accessing the categoryaccess wrongly

```js
console.log(response.data.categoryaccess)
```

Instead of this it should be

```
console.log(response.data[0].categoryaccess)
```

If data itself is an array you should loop over every element of the array to join category access of every element.

Comment: hi hardik, I have 2 arrays 0 amd 1. I will update the question. Thanks

Comment: In that case you should do something like response.data.map((element)=>{ *here you can access categoryaccess as element.categoryaccess* and you can do the operation you want with it.} )

Comment: Thanks. I did a map and am trying to join the array but it is not working. no error and is not showing anything. Here is the code: {data.categoryaccess._id.join(',')}. Thanks

Comment: categoryaccess itself is an array so if you want to get a single value after combining all the elements, you can try reduce() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce or if you want to do individual operations on every element of categoryaccess then you can loop over them using map() on categoryaccess